# ELSE back to before IF-ELSE statement (While True) in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, if-statement, while-loop, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have a problem that my `ELSE` condition need go back to the first position (Before IF-ELSE)

So, I have a Pipeline like this, my pipeline compare the value from Lookup (Query Table) and Databricks Output, and it will go to IF if value >, and go to ELSE if value <. But if it go through the ELSE statement, it will back to first Condition.

Is it possible to do that in ADF ?

This is my pipeline

[image]

And this is my False Condition

[image]

I want my False condition back to first condition as shown at first picture, and I need it until it got a True condition.

Comment: pipeline is a workflow, it can't return back.

Comment: @LeonYue Is there any activites from azure data factory that representation of while true condition ? or do you have any suggest for my pipeline ?

Comment: Hi @Rudy Tri Saputra, I'm afraid to say no, there isn't. I really hope to help you, but the logic can't be achieved in Data Factory.  It most like a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pipeline is a workflow, it can't return back.

I'm afraid to say there isn't any activites from azure data factory that representation of while true condition.  Just for now we can't achieve it.

Comment: I'm sorry ! I just opened stackoverflow again, thanks for the answer, I have found another way which is to override the existing method on my databricks